# Related List names are differ on Standard and Custom objects

Tags: page-layout

I have custom object tabs which appears as a related list to standard Account and some of the custom objects. However on Account, related lists are displaying correctly but not on the custom objects.

Below screen shot shows related lists on Account. This Shows 'Quickbooks' as prefix and friendly names for tabs
[image: This Shows 'Quickbooks' as prefix and friendly names for tabs]

Below screen shot shows related lists on Custom object. This lists does not shows 'Quickbooks' as prefix and not friendly names [image: This lists does not shows 'Quickbooks' as prefix and not friendly names]

Comment: That name is defined in the Invoice, SalesOrder and Sale objects. You need to go to the SObject lookup field on the 3 objects and change them to match the lookup fields to Account

Comment: Thank you!! I did not look at that part. It worked.

Comment: No problem. I've converted my comment to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That name is defined in the `Invoice`, `SalesOrder` and `Sale` objects. You need to go to the SObject lookup field on the 3 objects and change them to match the lookup fields to `Account`